# Sanitized text input for EntityMetadataWrapper set()

Tags: 7, entities, security

Through searching, I've found plenty of examples using the EntityMetadataWrapper `set()` function to update entity fields, and have implemented it successfully in my module. However, I haven't been able to find much in the way of documentation / best practices on the different array options you can pass to `set()`. I want to make sure the way I'm updating data won't cause unforeseen issues later on.

I am doing a straightforward update of text field values in a form submit callback:

```
function hook_FORM_ID_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the node.
  $node = node_load($form_state['nid']);

  // Create entity metadata wrapper to get and set values easily.
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node, array('bundle', $node->type));

  // Set fields
  $node_wrapper->field_quip->set(array("value" => $form_state['values']['field_quip']['value']));
  $node_wrapper->field_short_sentence_summary->set(array("value" => $form_state['values']['field_short_sentence_summary']['value']));

  // Save node.
  $node_wrapper->save();
}
```

I am passing `set()` an array with only one key: `value`. This seems to be working fine. However, I notice that when I call `value()` on that same field before I set a new value, it returns an array with three keys:

```
$original_value = $node_wrapper->field_quip->value();

// Output of $original_value:
// Array (
//   'value' => '<p>The original value</p>',
//   'format' => 'general',
//   'safe_value' => '<p>The original safe value</p>',
// )
```

The way I am current setting fields, I lose the sanitized value. Will this come back to bite me? Should I be running `check_markup()` on the value and passing `format` and `safe_value` to `set()`, rather than an array with just `value`? I might be splitting hairs here, but I want to make sure I do things right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that if you *just* set the `value`, Drupal will not display your HTML without converting your tags to entities. So the value `<p>Foo bar</p>` will be displayed literally in Views (and other areas) as `&lt;p&gt;Foo bar&lt;/p&gt;`.

Rather than attempt to create a sanitized `safe_value` myself before calling `set()`, I found that if I passed a `format` value, Drupal will take care of the sanitization for me with the filter settings defined for that format.

So the correct syntax is:

```
$quip = array(
  "value"  => $form_state['values']['field_quip']['value'],
  // Change to match the text format of your field.
  "format" => "general"
);
$node_wrapper->field_quip->set($quip);
```